# Unable to connect to Mongo Db Remotely

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently running 3.6 MongoDb on my local computer. I've downloaded the community edition, and am able to connect via Robo3t aka robomongo. 
I've installed the mongoDB instance on my Windows 10 machine like so:

```
mongod --install --logpath c:\mongodb\logs --logappend --bind_ip [127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0,192.168.0.141] --dbpath c:\data\db
```

I have also tried this with **just** 0.0.0.0. Same behavior

And I ran it:

```
net Start MongoDB
```

I'm able to connect to it locally:

[image]

I've opened up my firewall to allow connections of all types on my Windows machine:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open mongod port 27017" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=27017
```

I got my public IP address from "What's my IP", say xxx.xxx.xxx.177.

This is my current setup on Laptop1. Everything looks good.

So on Laptop2, I can ping xxx.xxx.xxx.177 no problem. But if I do a telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.177 27017 on Laptop2 I get a connect failed.

What steps am I missing, and what else can I do to try to connect to Laptop1? Everything seems to be running correctly locally.

Comment: Is Laptop1 on the same network as Laptop2, or are you trying to connect remotely using the public IP? If both laptops are on the same local network, the IP you want to connect is probably the local one (`192.168.0.141` in your example command line). If laptop2 is remotely connecting to the public IP ending in `.177`, I expect you need to create a firewall / port forwarding rule on your router so the external port 27017 is forwarded to your private IP and host. Note: it would be much more secure to remotely connect via VPN or SSH instead of opening a direct port forward to your database server.

Comment: After a few hours of hair pulling... it seemed I had the wrong IP address! I used ipconfig (vs what's my ip on google) and using that address worked.